# Pyspark mapping from a Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

If usually map my columns with the following method in pyspark:

> ```
>         Mapping_Typecom={"COM":"Commune a",
>                          "COMA":"Commune as",
>                          "ARM":"Arrond mun",
>                          "COMD":"Commun d"}
>         Mapping_Typecom = create_map([lit(x) for x in chain(*Mapping_Typecom.items())])
>         df = df.withColumn("Mapped", Mapping_Typect.getItem(col("typecom")))
> ```

So from a python dictionnary. I want to achieve the same result but from a pyspark dataframe:

> name | mappedvalue
>
> name1 | value1
>
> ....
>
> name2 | value2

I was thinking to transform my dataframe to a python dict, but I think that is not so effective as I will need to map 100 000 values. Is there a way to do so within the frame of pyspark?

Thank you for your help,

Comment: Can you update the sample input and expected output for better understanding?

Answer (score 0):

Someone mentions earlier (comment deleted apparently), to use a join with the mappedvalue dataframe, and the one I want to map. It did the job, thank him for his help :). Sometime you have to think the "easy" way.